# Not reading headphones on bootup until reattaching the wire

Tags: boot, sound, headphones

I have dual boot on the same harddrive SSD (windows 11 and ubuntu )

```js
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS
Release:    22.04
Codename:   jammy
```

After booting up every time always the system plays sound on the laptop's speakers, and must remove the headphone jack that was already connected and re-connect it so it works again.
Is there any solution for this annoying bug?